# Really messed up my MBR

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2

Pretty sure i've messed my MBR up. May not be the case, i'll give the evidence and let you decide.

I was attempting to setup a dual boot system. I have:
 60 GB SSD with windows 7 on it
 2 TB raid to go along with it
 1 TB HDD that linux was installed on.

My old boot summary can be found here:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6841705/

My new canbe found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6841777

I'm new to this. I'm just trying to get setup for classes.

Currently the SSD (win 7) is the first boot HDD from my BIOS. I've tried changing this to SDA as that is what the boot repair recommended doing. Linux won't bootup if i do that.

I'll redo whatever i have too, i'm basically out of ideas. I'm looking to get windows and ubuntu in a dual boot config, with linux on the 1TB drive, with windows on the SSD.

Comment: ALso, windows is not showing up under the ubuntu grub boot choice screen. Just the linux install and some mem test items. I'm assuming it's from what i messed up above.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional details to your question.  Adding details via comments is not recommended because comments can be lost/deleted without any history.  Please add specificity to the title so that future researchers can more immediately recognize what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 threads about this topic on the Ubuntu Forums.

You could try [fixing MBR after wrong removal of linux](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1666895) if you want to dual boot -- doing this means reinstalling Linux.

Otherwise, [Fixing grub](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1666885) should apply in your case.